# dart DateTime.add add 1 hours from a specific date

Tags: dart

I Would have a dart questions.

```
print(DateTime(2020,03,12).add(new Duration(days: 17)));
print(DateTime(2020,03,12).add(new Duration(days: 18)));
```

Results:

2020-03-29 00:00:00.000

2020-03-30 01:00:00.000

I don't understand the second result. Why 01:00:00?

This is the result running on Flutter test and dartpad.dev online, although if I run it from flutter application it shows 00:00:00 correctly. Why?

```
print(DateTime(2019,03,12).add(new Duration(days: 17)));

print(DateTime(2019,03,12).add(new Duration(days: 18)));
```

shows:

2019-03-29 00:00:00.000

2019-03-30 00:00:00.000

```
print(DateTime(2021,03,12).add(new Duration(days: 17)));

print(DateTime(2021,03,12).add(new Duration(days: 18)));
```

shows:

2021-03-29 01:00:00.000

2021-03-30 01:00:00.000

Comment: Your profile says you're from Hungary, and Google says that daylight saving time began in Hungary on March 29, 2020 at 2AM local time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is properly [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) since the `add` method does only understand seconds as documented in the API and the `Duration` are therefore converted to seconds before it is used:

> Notice that the duration being added is actually 50 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds. If the resulting DateTime has a different daylight saving offset than this, then the result won't have the same time-of-day as this, and may not even hit the calendar date 50 days later.
>
> Be careful when working with dates in local time.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/add.html

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to add 1 day to a DateTime is like this:

```
DateTime other = ...;
DateTime nextDay = DateTime(other.year, other.month, other.day + 1, other.hour, other.minute)
```

You can write an extension method like this:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime addDays(int days) => DateTime(year, month, day + days, hour, minute);
}
```

Also works when day + days is greater than 31.